# Prove or disprove that a holomorphic function with positive imaginary part is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{H}:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\text{Im}(z)>0\} $ be holomorphic. Prove or disprove that $ f $ is constant.

I first tried to prove it with Liouville's theorem by considering $ e^{-f(z)} $, which works for functions with a positive real part. But this approach didn't help me in this case. So then I tried to disprove it and think of a non-constant holomorphic function with positive imaginary part, but nothing came to mind.

I suppose the statement is false, but I don't know how to disprove it.

Any help or hints?

Comment: Maybe does $e^{-if(z)}$ helps?

Comment: I think $ e^{if(z)} $ works, actually, because then $ |e^{if(z)}|<1 $. So applying Liouville's theorem shows, that $ e^{if(z)} $  is constant. And from there I should be able to show that $ f $ is constant. Thanks for the food for thought!

Comment: You're welcome.